# Is there a way to 'absolute' the referred or target cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Absolute references are not changed when the referring cell is moved. But even with an absolute reference, if the *referred* cell moves the reference is updated. I want it to be dumber and continue to point to the same place even though the cell that was there moved, and pick up the content (a string) in what replaced the original cell. So, what I want is to define a ref to B5, add a new row 3 above B5, and still the ref points to B5. I haven't found a function to do this. Defining a Name doesn't help, nor does INDIRECT because both are updated to the new location of the original referred cell.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post does not have enough information for us to help you.  `INDIRECT` should work, but without seeing how you are using it we can't give any advice.  Please review site guidelines on [ask] and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Excel formula from changing when inserting/deleting rows](https://superuser.com/questions/1335789/stop-excel-formula-from-changing-when-inserting-deleting-rows)

Answer (score 0):

To point to B5 regardless of cell movements/insertions/deletions etc (or anything else) the formula `=INDIRECT("B" & "5", TRUE)` should work.

If you need it to work dynamically then the update should work in your favour to achieve the same, you could use `=INDIRECT("R" & B3 & "C" & B4, FALSE)` where the original cell (Row and Column) reference is held within cells B3 (5) and B4 (2) but correctly change if rows or columns are added before.  There are many other permutations to use the `INDIRECT` function.

Comment: Even simpler: `=INDIRECT("B5")`     :-)